# How to download the first or second picture in the Json?

Tags: json, swift3, imageview

I have an Json Code in Swift 3 and I want to get the first image in this json for my image view

another question: 
I want to know how can I get for example the second or the Third picture in the Json?

Here is my code

```
class thirdPhotoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var thirdImageJson: UIImageView!

final let urlString = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-sport&sortBy=top&apiKey=e6b2d66782ad421ba456b0c8b8b0ab79"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    func downloadJSONWithURL(){

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)! , completionHandler: { (data, response , error) -> Void in

            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
                as? NSDictionary {

                print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "articles"))


                if let titleArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "articles") as? NSArray {
                    for title in titleArray {
                        if let titleDict = title as? NSDictionary {
                            if let name = titleDict.value(forKey: "urlToImage") {
                                self.thirdImageJson.image.append(name as! String)
                                print("OK")
                            }
                            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                                //                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            })
                        }
                    }
                }





            }
        }).resume()
    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Show us `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: I don't Have table View I just have one Image View But I want to choose Which photo in Json shows in the Image View